# php sql upload picture to logged in user

Tags: php, sql

Hello I want to upload a pic to phpmyadmin and to store it to the loggen in user but can't manage it. And when I succed on uploading the image it goes to the first user.Want to return some rows of the table, but of the logged in user! Here is the code! Thanks

```
include('functions.php');
$upload_dir = 'images/';


if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));


    echo $file_name;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $file_size;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $file_tmp;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $file_type;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $file_ext;
    echo '<br>';


    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="Μόνο JPEG ή PNG file.";
    }

    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }

    if(empty($errors)==true){
        $path = $upload_dir.$file_name;
        echo $file_tmp.' >> '.$path;
        echo '<br>';

        //check the folder status _START
        if (!is_dir($upload_dir) || !is_writable($upload_dir)) {
            echo 'Upload directory('.$upload_dir.') is not writable, or does not exist.';
        }
        //_END

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_dir.$file_name)===TRUE) { 
            $logged_in_user_id = mysql_insert_id($db);
            $sql ="UPDATE users SET profile_image='$path' WHERE id='$id'";
            echo $sql;
            echo '<br>';


            $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

            echo "Success";    
        }
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Don't* put the image into the db, store a reference to where the file is stored and store the image in the file system and then put that stored reference in an img src.

Comment: if $logged_in_user_id is the uesr id what is $id used in the query?

Comment: `$logged_in_user_id = mysql_insert_id($db);` looks really....unlikely? Have you omitted some SQL?

Comment: Sfili_81 this is what happening every time I put logged_in_user

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: $logged_in_user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\aws_chat\personal_profile.php on line 53
UPDATE users SET profile_image='images/elijah.jpg' WHERE id=
Success

Comment: and apart from that everytime I do something like this  $logged_in_user_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
                $sql ="UPDATE users SET profile_image='$path'";

                echo $sql;
                echo '<br>';

                //PHP 7 line
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                //PHP 5 line
                //$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                echo "Success";    
            }

Comment: BTW, stop using `mysql_*`, make use of `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: the image uploading in both 2 users

Comment: `mysql_insert_id` gets the last inserted ID, so where are you inserting anything prior to executing that?

Comment: here! <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<div id="content">
<form action="personal_profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000" />
 <input type="file" name="image">
 <div class="msg-box">
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Image">
 </div>
</form>
</div>

Comment: Here... what? What's there? It's just a block of HTML that nobody asked for?

Comment: Script47 I just uploading images for a chat I make in phpmyadmin, and want every image that is uploading to go to the logged in user and in general every user to have his own image. I didn't understand the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in how you get the user ID for your insert:

```
$logged_in_user_id = mysql_insert_id($db)
```

`mysql_insert_id($db)` will get the ID of your last insert that generates an autoincrement. I do not believe it will work as intended if you have closed the connection after your insert. If your insert is on a different script, use sessions or `$_GET` or `$_POST` to transfer your user ID.

Also the reason could be incompatibility between packages:

you are using `mysqli` to write to db. but retrieving the last ID with `mysql` package. `mysqli` also has a method for this operation: `mysqli_insert_id()`

Also you get your user ID in to variable `$logged_in_user_id` but in your query you are using variable `$id`...